# Improving minimax algorithm for Gomoku AI with transposition table?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I'm building an AI for Gomoku (16x16) with minimax and alpha-beta pruning but it's very slow. So far, I have tried pre-sorting the order of moves and instead of deep copying the board, adding and later removing the moves. Also, I use an arraylist of relevant moves(which are within a radius of 2 to already placed pieces) to reduce the search board. Yet the AI still struggles even at a depth search of 3.
Edit: I have found out about something called transposition table, but I don't know where to start. Any help would be great!

```
private double minimax(Board node, String player, int depth, double lowerBound, double upperBound){
    if (depth==3){
        return node.evaluate();
    }

    if (player.equals(humanPiece)) {// min node
        // sort setup
        ArrayList<int[]> relevantMoves = node.relevantMoves();
        HashMap<int[], Double> moveValueTable = new HashMap<>();

        for (int[] move: relevantMoves){
            node.addMove(move[0], move[1], player);
            double val = node.evaluate();
            moveValueTable.put(move, val);
            node.retractMove(move[0], move[1]);
        }
        // insertion sort from small to big (alpha-beta optimization)
        insertionSort(relevantMoves, moveValueTable);
        result = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        // minimax
        for (int[] move : relevantMoves) {  // y first, x second
            node.addMove(move[0], move[1], player);
            double score = minimax(node, node.getEnemy(player), depth+1, lowerBound, upperBound);
            node.retractMove(move[0], move[1]);
            if (score < upperBound) {
                upperBound = score;
            }
            if (score < result) result = score;
            if (lowerBound > upperBound) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    else{// max node
        // sort setup
        ArrayList<int[]> relevantMoves = node.relevantMoves();
        HashMap<int[], Double> moveValueTable = new HashMap<>();

        for (int[] move: relevantMoves){
            node.addMove(move[0], move[1], player);
            double val = node.evaluate();
            moveValueTable.put(move, val);
            node.retractMove(move[0], move[1]);
        }
        // insertion sort from big to small (alpha-beta optimization)
        reversedInsertionSort(relevantMoves, moveValueTable);
        result = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        // minimax
        for (int[] move : relevantMoves) {  // y first, x second
            node.addMove(move[0], move[1], player);
            double score = minimax(node, node.getEnemy(player), depth+1, lowerBound, upperBound);
            node.retractMove(move[0], move[1]);
            if (score > lowerBound) {
                lowerBound = score;
            }
            if (score > result) result = score;
            if (lowerBound > upperBound) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having never encountered this AI thing, you seem to be doing a lot of `addMove` and `retractMove`, yet you actually interested in mins and maxes it looks like. How about instead of collecting a table of all values you do a single pass of looking for interesting values?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I don't understand. can you clarify?

Comment: You iterate all relevant moves two times for each node you encounter. What I suggested was doing this iteration only once. This unfortunately forbids you from doing "alpha-beta optimization", whatever that is. Have you actually profiled your code with and without this optimization? Does it help? What will happen if you remove it?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It helps a lot bc on average I can cut off large portion of the search tree without having to calculate them. If I remove them, I will get terrible worst cases.

Comment: Does that mean you sacrificed your best-case for better worst-case? You should definitely profile this and see where is the bottleneck. It may even be `addMove/retractMove`, we don't know since there's no implementation detail available for it in question.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good explanation of how transposition tables work: [TT](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Transposition+Table)

It can improve your search speed by eliminating transposition from the search tree. Transpositions are positions that can be attained by two or more different sequences of moves. Some games, like chess or checkers have plenty of transpositions, others have very little or even none.

Once you have the transposition table in place, it is easy to add more speed optimizations that rely on it.

Comment: I get the essence, but I am having trouble of implementing it. Can you give me some ideas?